# Decltype of function call discards const qualifiers

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, return-value, decltype

Consider a function

```
template <typename T>
    const T&& foo();
```

When i had tried to tested it,i founded result that I didn't understand. Output is 0.

```
#include <iostream>

class C{};

template <typename T>
    const T&& foo();

int main() {
    std::cout << std::is_same_v<decltype(foo<C&&>()), const C&&>;
    return 0;
}
```

Shouldn't decltype preserve const qualifiers? In my opinion, it should be like `T-> C&&`, so return type is `const C&&` via reference collapsing rules, and decltype of result is `const C&&`

Also, this line

```
std::cout << std::is_same_v<decltype(foo<int>()), const int&&> << '\n';
```

Prints 1 as expected.

Can somebody help me to figure out correct logic of working?

I found that when decltype applied on non-class prvalue, cv qualifiers are discarded. But this is not the case, because value category of `foo<int&&>()` is xvalue, and this also doesn't works with class type `C`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Shouldn't decltype preserve const qualifiers?

Yes, and it does here as well. The return type of `foo<C&&>()` really is `C&&`, not `const C&&`.

> In my opinion, it should be like T-> C&&, so return type is const C&& via reference collapsing rules, and decltype of result is const C&&

No, you are applying `const` to `T` first, then `&&` afterwards.

`const T&&` means "*rvalue reference to (`const T`)*". It doesn't mean "*`const` (rvalue reference to `T`)*".

The `const` is applied *at top-level* to `T`. That means if `T` is `C&&` you are trying to `const`-qualify a reference, but there are no `const`-qualified references in C++. So the language rules say that `const` is ignored when trying to `const`-qualify a reference through such a construction.

---

> std::cout << std::is_same_v<decltype(foo()), const int&&> << '\n';

Here you are applying `const` to `int` giving you `const int` and then you add `&&` on top. So you get `const int&&`.

> I found that when decltype applied on non-class prvalue, cv qualifiers are discarded.

They are discarded on the non-class type prvalue expression, but not on the return type of the function itself. If a function is declared to return `const T` and you substitute `int` for `T`, then the function has return type `const int`, but a call to the function is a prvalue expression of type `int`.

> But this is not the case, because value category of foo<int&&>() is xvalue, and this also doesn't works with class type C.

Yes, correct. This special rule doesn't matter here. `decltype` does faithfully reproduce the declared return type.

Comment: Perfect Analysis. This is why I like writing it like `T const &&` ( syntactically equivalent to `const T&&`) as it is easier to read (right to left). Unfortunately I feel my style is more old school nowadays. :-)